# Vertical equivalent for \overbrace and \underbrace

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

Is there a way to label a vector like this in LaTeX? (like `\overbrace`/`\underbrace` but vertically)

```
a \
a  |
a   > Segment a
a  |
a /
b \
b  |
b   > Segment b
b  |
b /
```

I assume I can't be the first one that asks that, however I was not able to find anything helpful.

Comment: Use `\left. .... \right\}`. Note the use of dot after `\left`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
\left.
\begin{array}{rrr}
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a
\end{array}
\right\}\text{Segment a}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:** 
I see, in your case, you will want to use `bigdelim` package, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{cc}
a&\rdelim\}{5}{1em}[Segment a]\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
b&\rdelim\}{5}{1em}[Segment b]\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

will give you:

[image]

Comment: i knew that possibility, but it is not quite what I am looking for, because I need to have more than one Segment. Maybe I just don't quite get what you mean, but if I see this correctly this only works for one segment.
If I put the second segment below the first one I can't use the usual vector brackets, or else each array will be in its own bracket

Comment: @kyra: updated.

Answer (score 7):

Another way using the `rcases` environment from `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$
    \begin{rcases}
        a\\a\\a\\a\\a
    \end{rcases}
    \text{Segment A}
$\\
$
    \begin{rcases}
        b\\b\\b\\b\\b
    \end{rcases}
    \text{Segment B}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Improving the @Francis's code, you can use two rows with two blocks.

```
\[
\begin{array}{r}
\left. \begin{array}{r}
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a
\end{array}
\right\}\text{Segment a} \\
\left. \begin{array}{r}
b\\
b\\
b\\
b\\
b
\end{array}
\right\}\text{Segment b}
\end{array} 
\]
```

[image]